# Adjust the size of bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap dropdown for the second textbox. That has a large content. I need to resize to the size of its dropping textbox. The dropdown overflows and spreads to other textbox on the left below.

**UPDATE:**

The dropdown should be confined to RED indicated area as shown in the below image

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>
    .dropdown .list-group-item {
      width: 100px!important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="input-group">
    <button type="button" role="button" title="Delete" class="material-symbols-outlined text-secondary input-group-text bg-theme delrow">delete</button>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Key" class="form-control key">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Value" class="form-control form-select value suggest coltitle-tags meta-tags typeable dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">

    <div class="dropdown-menu border-secondary fdropdown-menu show" data-popper-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px auto auto 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate3d(16.8px, 38.4px, 0px);">
      <div>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Type to search..." class="m-3 mt-2 form-control search"> <span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Timestamp}}" title="Timestamp
    " href="#">Timestamp</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Email Address}}" title="Email Address
    ⓘ Column B" href="#">Email Address</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Class name}}" title="Class name
    ⓘ Column C" href="#">Class name</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Instructor}}" title="Instructor
    ⓘ Column D" href="#">Instructor</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Level of effort [Level of effort you put into the course]}}" title="Level of effort [Level of effort you put into the course]
    ⓘ Column E" href="#">Level of effort [Level of effort you put into the course]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Contribution to learning}}" title="Contribution to learning
    ⓘ Column F" href="#">Contribution to learning</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was an effective lecturer/demonstrator]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was an effective lecturer/demonstrator]
    ⓘ Column G" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was an effective lecturer/demonstrator]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Presentations were clear and organized]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Presentations were clear and organized]
    ⓘ Column H" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Presentations were clear and organized]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor stimulated student interest]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor stimulated student interest]
    ⓘ Column I" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor stimulated student interest]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor effectively used time during class periods]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor effectively used time during class periods]
    ⓘ Column J" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor effectively used time during class periods]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was available and helpful]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was available and helpful]
    ⓘ Column K" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was available and helpful]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Grading was prompt and had useful feedback]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Grading was prompt and had useful feedback]
    ⓘ Column L" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Grading was prompt and had useful feedback]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Learning objectives were clear]}}" title="Course content [Learning objectives were clear]
    ⓘ Column M" href="#">Course content [Learning objectives were clear]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Course content was organized and well planned]}}" title="Course content [Course content was organized and well planned]
    ⓘ Column N" href="#">Course content [Course content was organized and well planned]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Course workload was appropriate]}}" title="Course content [Course workload was appropriate]
    ⓘ Column O" href="#">Course content [Course workload was appropriate]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Course organized to allow all students to participate fully]}}" title="Course content [Course organized to allow all students to participate fully]
    ⓘ Column P" href="#">Course content [Course organized to allow all students to participate fully]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{What aspects of this course were most useful or valuable?}}" title="What aspects of this course were most useful or valuable?
    ⓘ Column Q" href="#">What aspects of this course were most useful or valuable?</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{How would you improve this course?}}" title="How would you improve this course?
    ⓘ Column R" href="#">How would you improve this course?</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Why did you choose this course?}}" title="Why did you choose this course?
    ⓘ Column S" href="#">Why did you choose this course?</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Instructor}}" title="Instructor
    ⓘ Column T" href="#">Instructor</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Level of effort [Level of effort you put into the course]}}" title="Level of effort [Level of effort you put into the course]
    ⓘ Column U" href="#">Level of effort [Level of effort you put into the course]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Contribution to learning}}" title="Contribution to learning
    ⓘ Column V" href="#">Contribution to learning</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was an effective lecturer/demonstrator]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was an effective lecturer/demonstrator]
    ⓘ Column W" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was an effective lecturer/demonstrator]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Presentations were clear and organized]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Presentations were clear and organized]
    ⓘ Column X" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Presentations were clear and organized]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor stimulated student interest]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor stimulated student interest]
    ⓘ Column Y" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor stimulated student interest]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor effectively used time during class periods]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor effectively used time during class periods]
    ⓘ Column Z" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor effectively used time during class periods]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was available and helpful]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was available and helpful]
    ⓘ Column AA" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was available and helpful]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Grading was prompt and had useful feedback]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Grading was prompt and had useful feedback]
    ⓘ Column AB" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Grading was prompt and had useful feedback]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Learning objectives were clear]}}" title="Course content [Learning objectives were clear]
    ⓘ Column AC" href="#">Course content [Learning objectives were clear]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Course content was organized and well planned]}}" title="Course content [Course content was organized and well planned]
    ⓘ Column AD" href="#">Course content [Course content was organized and well planned]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Course workload was appropriate]}}" title="Course content [Course workload was appropriate]
    ⓘ Column AE" href="#">Course content [Course workload was appropriate]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Course organized to allow all students to participate fully]}}" title="Course content [Course organized to allow all students to participate fully]
    ⓘ Column AF" href="#">Course content [Course organized to allow all students to participate fully]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{What aspects of this course were most useful or valuable?}}" title="What aspects of this course were most useful or valuable?
    ⓘ Column AG" href="#">What aspects of this course were most useful or valuable?</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{How would you improve this course?}}" title="How would you improve this course?
    ⓘ Column AH" href="#">How would you improve this course?</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Why did you choose this course?}}" title="Why did you choose this course?
    ⓘ Column AI" href="#">Why did you choose this course?</a></span>
        <li>
          <hr class="dropdown-divider">
        </li>
        <span class="dropdown-tag-meta"><a class="dropdown-tag-meta-item" data-value="{{Response Number}}" title="Response Number
    ⓘ Form Response number" href="#"> Response Number </a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-meta"><a class="dropdown-tag-meta-item" data-value="{{Form Name}}" title="Form Name
    ⓘ The name of the Google Form" href="#"> Form Name </a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-meta"><a class="dropdown-tag-meta-item" data-value="{{Form Url}}" title="Form Url
    ⓘ A link to the associated Google Form" href="#"> Form Url </a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-meta"><a class="dropdown-tag-meta-item" data-value="{{Response Id}}" title="Response Id
    ⓘ Unique response ID generated by Google Form" href="#"> Response Id </a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-meta"><a class="dropdown-tag-meta-item" data-value="{{Response Url}}" title="Response Url
    ⓘ Directly link to view / edit the current form submission" href="#"> Response Url </a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-meta"><a class="dropdown-tag-meta-item" data-value="{{Response Date}}" title="Response Date
    ⓘ The full timestamp when a form was submitted" href="#"> Response Date </a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-meta"><a class="dropdown-tag-meta-item" data-value="{{All Markers}}" title="All Markers
    ⓘ An HTML table containing all the form responses in a neat tabular format." href="#"> All Markers </a></span>
      </div>
    </div>


    <button type="button" role="button" title="Add new" class="material-symbols-outlined input-group-text bg-theme addrow">add</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(`body`).on("click", '.addrow,.addnewrow', function() {
        $(this).parent().after(`<div class="input-group">
                        <button type="button" role="button" title="Delete" class="material-symbols-outlined input-group-text bg-theme delnewrow">delete</button>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Key" class="form-control key">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Value" class="form-control form-select value suggest coltitle-tags meta-tags typeable dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
                        <button type="button" role="button" title="Add new" class="material-symbols-outlined input-group-text bg-theme addnewrow">add</button>
                            </div>`);
        addsuggest(wid, tid);
      }).on("click", '.delnewrow', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: by looking at the docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#dropdowns i can see the `.dropdown-menu` is inside `.dropdown` ,  the `.dropdown` container is missing in your code

Answer (score 0):

I quickly tried what i posted as a comment, so i just added a .dropdown wrapper and it kinda goes into the right direction

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>
    .dropdown .list-group-item {
      width: 100px!important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="input-group">
    <button type="button" role="button" title="Delete" class="material-symbols-outlined text-secondary input-group-text bg-theme delrow">delete</button>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Key" class="form-control key">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Value" class="form-control form-select value suggest coltitle-tags meta-tags typeable dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-menu border-secondary fdropdown-menu " data-popper-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px auto auto 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate3d(16.8px, 38.4px, 0px);">
      <div>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Type to search..." class="m-3 mt-2 form-control search"> <span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Timestamp}}" title="Timestamp
    " href="#">Timestamp</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Email Address}}" title="Email Address
    ⓘ Column B" href="#">Email Address</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Class name}}" title="Class name
    ⓘ Column C" href="#">Class name</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Instructor}}" title="Instructor
    ⓘ Column D" href="#">Instructor</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Level of effort [Level of effort you put into the course]}}" title="Level of effort [Level of effort you put into the course]
    ⓘ Column E" href="#">Level of effort [Level of effort you put into the course]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Contribution to learning}}" title="Contribution to learning
    ⓘ Column F" href="#">Contribution to learning</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was an effective lecturer/demonstrator]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was an effective lecturer/demonstrator]
    ⓘ Column G" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was an effective lecturer/demonstrator]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Presentations were clear and organized]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Presentations were clear and organized]
    ⓘ Column H" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Presentations were clear and organized]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor stimulated student interest]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor stimulated student interest]
    ⓘ Column I" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor stimulated student interest]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor effectively used time during class periods]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor effectively used time during class periods]
    ⓘ Column J" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor effectively used time during class periods]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was available and helpful]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was available and helpful]
    ⓘ Column K" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was available and helpful]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Grading was prompt and had useful feedback]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Grading was prompt and had useful feedback]
    ⓘ Column L" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Grading was prompt and had useful feedback]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Learning objectives were clear]}}" title="Course content [Learning objectives were clear]
    ⓘ Column M" href="#">Course content [Learning objectives were clear]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Course content was organized and well planned]}}" title="Course content [Course content was organized and well planned]
    ⓘ Column N" href="#">Course content [Course content was organized and well planned]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Course workload was appropriate]}}" title="Course content [Course workload was appropriate]
    ⓘ Column O" href="#">Course content [Course workload was appropriate]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Course organized to allow all students to participate fully]}}" title="Course content [Course organized to allow all students to participate fully]
    ⓘ Column P" href="#">Course content [Course organized to allow all students to participate fully]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{What aspects of this course were most useful or valuable?}}" title="What aspects of this course were most useful or valuable?
    ⓘ Column Q" href="#">What aspects of this course were most useful or valuable?</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{How would you improve this course?}}" title="How would you improve this course?
    ⓘ Column R" href="#">How would you improve this course?</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Why did you choose this course?}}" title="Why did you choose this course?
    ⓘ Column S" href="#">Why did you choose this course?</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Instructor}}" title="Instructor
    ⓘ Column T" href="#">Instructor</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Level of effort [Level of effort you put into the course]}}" title="Level of effort [Level of effort you put into the course]
    ⓘ Column U" href="#">Level of effort [Level of effort you put into the course]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Contribution to learning}}" title="Contribution to learning
    ⓘ Column V" href="#">Contribution to learning</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was an effective lecturer/demonstrator]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was an effective lecturer/demonstrator]
    ⓘ Column W" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was an effective lecturer/demonstrator]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Presentations were clear and organized]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Presentations were clear and organized]
    ⓘ Column X" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Presentations were clear and organized]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor stimulated student interest]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor stimulated student interest]
    ⓘ Column Y" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor stimulated student interest]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor effectively used time during class periods]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor effectively used time during class periods]
    ⓘ Column Z" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor effectively used time during class periods]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was available and helpful]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was available and helpful]
    ⓘ Column AA" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Instructor was available and helpful]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Grading was prompt and had useful feedback]}}" title="Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Grading was prompt and had useful feedback]
    ⓘ Column AB" href="#">Skill and responsiveness of the instructor [Grading was prompt and had useful feedback]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Learning objectives were clear]}}" title="Course content [Learning objectives were clear]
    ⓘ Column AC" href="#">Course content [Learning objectives were clear]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Course content was organized and well planned]}}" title="Course content [Course content was organized and well planned]
    ⓘ Column AD" href="#">Course content [Course content was organized and well planned]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Course workload was appropriate]}}" title="Course content [Course workload was appropriate]
    ⓘ Column AE" href="#">Course content [Course workload was appropriate]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Course content [Course organized to allow all students to participate fully]}}" title="Course content [Course organized to allow all students to participate fully]
    ⓘ Column AF" href="#">Course content [Course organized to allow all students to participate fully]</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{What aspects of this course were most useful or valuable?}}" title="What aspects of this course were most useful or valuable?
    ⓘ Column AG" href="#">What aspects of this course were most useful or valuable?</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{How would you improve this course?}}" title="How would you improve this course?
    ⓘ Column AH" href="#">How would you improve this course?</a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-questions"><a class="dropdown-tag-questions-item" data-value="{{Why did you choose this course?}}" title="Why did you choose this course?
    ⓘ Column AI" href="#">Why did you choose this course?</a></span>
        <li>
          <hr class="dropdown-divider">
        </li>
        <span class="dropdown-tag-meta"><a class="dropdown-tag-meta-item" data-value="{{Response Number}}" title="Response Number
    ⓘ Form Response number" href="#"> Response Number </a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-meta"><a class="dropdown-tag-meta-item" data-value="{{Form Name}}" title="Form Name
    ⓘ The name of the Google Form" href="#"> Form Name </a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-meta"><a class="dropdown-tag-meta-item" data-value="{{Form Url}}" title="Form Url
    ⓘ A link to the associated Google Form" href="#"> Form Url </a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-meta"><a class="dropdown-tag-meta-item" data-value="{{Response Id}}" title="Response Id
    ⓘ Unique response ID generated by Google Form" href="#"> Response Id </a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-meta"><a class="dropdown-tag-meta-item" data-value="{{Response Url}}" title="Response Url
    ⓘ Directly link to view / edit the current form submission" href="#"> Response Url </a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-meta"><a class="dropdown-tag-meta-item" data-value="{{Response Date}}" title="Response Date
    ⓘ The full timestamp when a form was submitted" href="#"> Response Date </a></span><span class="dropdown-tag-meta"><a class="dropdown-tag-meta-item" data-value="{{All Markers}}" title="All Markers
    ⓘ An HTML table containing all the form responses in a neat tabular format." href="#"> All Markers </a></span>
      </div></div>
    </div>


    <button type="button" role="button" title="Add new" class="material-symbols-outlined input-group-text bg-theme addrow">add</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(`body`).on("click", '.addrow,.addnewrow', function() {
        $(this).parent().after(`<div class="input-group">
                        <button type="button" role="button" title="Delete" class="material-symbols-outlined input-group-text bg-theme delnewrow">delete</button>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Key" class="form-control key">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Value" class="form-control form-select value suggest coltitle-tags meta-tags typeable dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">
                        <button type="button" role="button" title="Add new" class="material-symbols-outlined input-group-text bg-theme addnewrow">add</button>
                            </div>`);
        addsuggest(wid, tid);
      }).on("click", '.delnewrow', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```